# Find max value in a group in FileMaker

Tags: filemaker

How to select only max values in a group in the following set

```
id  productid  price  year
---------------------------
1   11         0,10   2015
2   11         0,12   2016
3   11         0,11   2017
4   22         0,08   2016
5   33         0,02   2016
6   33         0,01   2017
```

Expected result for each productid and max year would be

```
id  productid  price  year
---------------------------
3   11         0,11   2017
4   22         0,08   2016
6   33         0,01   2017
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me.

```
ExecuteSQL (
"SELECT t.id, t.productid, t.price, t.\"year\"
    FROM test t
    WHERE \"year\" = 
        (SELECT MAX(\"year\") FROM test tt WHERE t.productid = tt.productid)"
; "  " ; "")
```

Adapted from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21310671/832407

Answer (score 0):

A simple SQL query will give you a last year for every product record

```
ExecuteSQL ( 
            "SELECT productid, MAX ( \"year\") 
             FROM myTable
             GROUP By productid";
 "";"" )
```

To get to the price for that year is going to be trickier, as FileMaker SQL does not fully support subqueries or temp tables.